# Django query return array data

Tags: django, postgresql

I want to query some values from my Postgresql database in Django and want to show in my table. but problem is I am getting some array data like **['Dish', 'LNB Inverto']**. I want to show values in my table like

```
                           Dish|   1000 |  5  |5000
                           -------------------------
                           LNB |    500 |  10 |5000
                           -------------------------
```

my views:

```
    def purchaseDetails(request,pk):
           invo_data = PurchaseInvoice.objects.all().filter(invoice=pk)
           return render(request,'purchase/invoice_details.html',{'invoice':invo_data})
```

my html:

```
                {% for data in invoice %}
                        <tr><td>
                             {{data.product_name}}
                        </td><td>
                                {{data.price}}
                        </td><td>
                                {{data.quantity}}
                        </td></tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

I am getting like **['Dish', 'LNB Inverto'] ['810.00', '214.00']    ['8', '8']**

my models

```
              class PurchaseInvoice(models.Model):
                        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
                        vendor = models.CharField(max_length=50)
                        invoice = models.CharField(max_length=20)
                        date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
                        product_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
                        price = models.CharField(max_length=300)
                        quantity = models.CharField(max_length=200)
                        amount = models.CharField(max_length=300)

                        def __str__(self):
                        return self.invoice
```

Comment: Show us your models.py

Comment: product_name, price, quantity and amount inserted multiple values.